# SharePoint Authentication REST API Java

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint-2013

This is regarding the post: [BASIC authentication from JAVA to Sharepoint 2013 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570383/basic-authentication-from-java-to-sharepoint-2013-rest-api)

I am facing the same problem.

I tried the solutions provided over here but it did not work out for me.
I am trying my luck to get the SharePoint Rest API working with Java but to no avail. It is showing the below error response:

```
Oct 03, 2017 8:23:49 PM org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator generateAuthResponse

WARNING: NEGOTIATE authentication error:
No valid credentials provided
(Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided
(Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Processed
```

Comment: same with me. no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled NTLM authentication , then you can try NTLM auth from java. This example might help you , because following the same worked for me .

http://www.muneebahmad.com/index.php/archives/127

If you have Digest type of auth then you can refer this ,

http://www.whypad.com/posts/authenticate-sharepoint-rest-call-in-a-rest-client/1169/

Comment: it did not work. tried it out, still getting the same error

Comment: are you hitting the domain controller machine ( where the sharepoint is installed )  with the installed port ? I sometimes get 500 server error , that time I RDPlogin controller vm and hit the api (http://localhost:1026/_api/web/lists) using REST cli using firefox [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/restclient/) , after that again I try from external vm it worked and responded 200 instead of 500.. Other than that I have never faced any issues.  Also in IIS Admin CP , check windows auth is enabled .

Comment: Actually, when i try to hit the rest api from local machine using browser, it works, but when i am trying to do that programatically, it does not work. I am working in an SSO (Single Sign-on) environment, if that could cause any issue.

Comment: What type of authentication you are using for   sharpoint ? NTLM ( windows domain users ) or kerbros ?

Comment: We are using NTLM

Comment: @RatnadipChaudhuri we are also using the same .. that Java sample works flawlessly. Check it out man.

Comment: hi, my fault, we are using kerberos... now how can i go forward?

Comment: @ArunKumarGR Have you got any luck to solve the 500 server error issue?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa it happens cuz of login. hit an sharepoint api from sharepoint server itself in firefox . It will ask for login , use credentials to login and the error will go off. It was the workaround then but now I am not working on that. Good luck for finding the real cause .