# Upload file to SharePoint by Java

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, upload, http-post

After success check the SharePoint link exit by the code below,
I want to upload a file to that SharePoint link, How can I achieve that
Example:

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://hostname/.../folderName");

File file = new File(Path);

//what is next step that need to do?

code-link: [BASIC authentication from JAVA to Sharepoint 2013 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570383/basic-authentication-from-java-to-sharepoint-2013-rest-api)

```
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class SharePointClientAuthentication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
            new NTCredentials("username", "password", "https://hostname", "domain"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://hostname/.../folderName");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
}
```

Upload file to Share Point in Java